# Select multiple rows as one row in two different fields name by MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: one is d_sms and the other is d_image table.  I have two images for each sms_id: the first is the main image and the second is the offer image.
I want to select these images by image_id and image_offer_id. The problem that I give the two images but in two rows. I need to select the image and offer_image in one row. How to do that?

**This code give me two rows**

```
SELECT d_sms.*
     , d_image.*
        FROM
          d_sms
        INNER  JOIN d_image
        ON d_sms.image_id = d_image.id
        or d_sms.offer_image_id = d_image.id
```

Comment: If you put some data in a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com), I'd be happy to give you a hand.

Comment: how do you know which one is 'first' and which one is 'second'?

Comment: the basic answer here is that you link in the image table twice to the same query - but you don't give enough info or sample data to actually help.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16b2d

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to do two separate joins:

```
select d_sms.*, i.*, oi.*
from d_sms left outer join
    d_image i
    on d_sms.image_id = i.id left outer join
    d_image oi
    on d_sms.offer_image_id = oi.id;
```

Note:  You will want to choose individual fields from `oi` and `i` and give them different names.

Comment: Agree with the two separate joins; it is not clear that they need to be LOJ, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler . . . I just wanted to be careful for the case where there are not two images.

Comment: select d_sms.*, i.*, oi.*,   
i.raw_name as x,
oi.raw_name as xx
from d_sms left outer join
    d_image i
    on d_sms.image_id = i.id left outer join
    d_image oi
    on d_sms.offer_image_id = oi.id;

Comment: @user1080247 . . . You should list all the columns you want and not use the `*` syntax.  `oi` and `i` have the same columns, so you will have column conflicts unless you say something like `i.raw_name as i_raw_name, oi.raw_name as oi_raw_name, . . .`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.id, i.imag, i2.imag from d_sms s 
inner join  d_image i on s.image_id = i.imageid
inner join  d_image i2 on s.offer_image_id = i2.imageid
```

Agreeing with Randy about the two joins. If both images exist then inner joins will probably be more efficient.